# Problem using generics in function

Tags: java, generics

I have this functions and need to make it one function. The only difference is type of input variable *sourceColumnValue*. This variable can be *String* or *Integer* but the return value of function must be always *Integer*.
I know I need to use Generics but can't do it.

```
    public Integer selectReturnInt(String tableName, String sourceColumnName, String sourceColumnValue, String targetColumnName) {
    Integer returned = null;
    String query = "SELECT "+targetColumnName+" FROM "+tableName+" WHERE "+sourceColumnName+"='"+sourceColumnValue+"' LIMIT 1";

    try {
        Connection connection = ConnectionManager.getInstance().open();
        java.sql.Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute(query.toString());
        ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next()){
            returned = rs.getInt(targetColumnName);
        }

        rs.close();
        statement.close();
        ConnectionManager.getInstance().close(connection);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Заявката не може да бъде изпълнена!");
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return returned;
}


// SELECT (RETURN INTEGER)
public Integer selectIntReturnInt(String tableName, String sourceColumnName, Integer sourceColumnValue, String targetColumnName) {
    Integer returned = null;
    String query = "SELECT "+targetColumnName+" FROM "+tableName+" WHERE "+sourceColumnName+"='"+sourceColumnValue+"' LIMIT 1";

    try {
        Connection connection = ConnectionManager.getInstance().open();
        java.sql.Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute(query.toString());
        ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next()){
            returned = rs.getInt(targetColumnName);
        }

        rs.close();
        statement.close();
        ConnectionManager.getInstance().close(connection);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Заявката не може да бъде изпълнена!");
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return returned;
}
```

Comment: looks like some frustrated psychopath came and down-voted everyone ([mee too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133958/problem-using-generics-in-function/5133995#5133995)) :D

Comment: Never use String concatenation for SQL, it's a security risk and an anti-pattern: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/ Also release claimed resources in finally instead of they try block (otherwise failures will not release claimed resources!).

Answer (score 1):

**No** you don't need to use generics for this.. generic should be used when your supported Types can be to many and you don't know about them before hand and they share something common in them.

Only for just two Types Generics is not a good choice. Using `objects`  can be a better choice.

*May be i will say you don't even need to merge these functions, that's what polymorphism is for. keeping things discreet will allow more readability of code*

Answer (score 0):

No need to use generic, you can just use Object as the variable type for the function :

```
public Integer selectIntReturnInt(String tableName, String sourceColumnName, Object sourceColumnValue, String targetColumnName) {
    Integer returned = null;
    String query = "SELECT "+targetColumnName+" FROM "+tableName+" WHERE "+sourceColumnName+"='"+sourceColumnValue.toString()+"' LIMIT 1";

    try {
        Connection connection = ConnectionManager.getInstance().open();
        java.sql.Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute(query.toString());
        ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next()){
            returned = rs.getInt(targetColumnName);
        }

        rs.close();
        statement.close();
        ConnectionManager.getInstance().close(connection);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Заявката не може да бъде изпълнена!");
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return returned;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use generics. Just declare it as

```
public Integer selectReturnInt(String tableName, 
      String sourceColumnName, 
      Object sourceColumnValue, 
      String targetColumnName) {
      ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the second method just call the first:

```
public Integer selectIntReturnInt(String tableName, String sourceColumnName, Integer sourceColumnValue, String targetColumnName) {
    return selectReturnInt(tableName, sourceColumnName, sourceColumnValue.toString(), targetColumnName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the love $deity please don't use dynamic SQL. You will get injection vulnerabilities.

You want to break this into (at least) three method. One with the bulk of the implementation, and one each for the different types.

Also of note:

- Resource handling should be of the form `final Resource resource = acquire(); try { ... } finally { resource.release(); }`, or in JDK7 `try (final Resource resource = acquire()) { ... }`.
- Singletons are the work of the devil.
- Exception handling considered a good idea, whereas sinking to a `printf` is bad.
- You're probably better off only returning a value if there is exactly one result set and throwing an exception otherwise.